# Aurelia auth response

Tags: http, error-handling, response, aurelia, aurelia-auth

I am using aurelia auth for login. But I can't get error message from server. In catch method err.response is undefined. Err is object with body of type Readable stream. Below is my code:

```
this.auth.login(bodyContent)
  .then(response=>{
  })
  .catch(err=>{
    console.log(err);
    console.log(err.response);
  });
```

in chrome developer tools I can see response message.
This is err printed:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution here (https://gist.github.com/bryanrsmith/14caed2015b9c54e70c3) and it is the following:

```
.catch(error => error.json().then(serverError =>
  console.log(serverError) 
}));
```

The explanation can be found in the Aurelia docs:

> The Fetch API has no convenient way of sending JSON in the body of a request. Objects must be manually serialized to JSON, and the `Content-Type` header set appropriately. aurelia-fetch-client includes a helper called `json` for this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42532109/aurelia-auth-custom-response-message-console-error

Comment: Did you find a way to suppress the console error when returning a Unauthorized response from server?

Answer (score 1):

I also came across this same question recently.

I ended up creating a class called FetchError to encapsulate these sorts of errors. I then throw FetchError whenever an error occurs during a fetch.

login.ts:

```
import { FetchError } from '../../errors';

  login() {
    var credentials = { grant_type: "password", username: this.username, password: this.password };
    return this.auth.login(credentials, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } })
      .then((response) => {
        return this.auth;
      }).catch(err => {
        this.errorMessage = "Login failed";
        throw new FetchError("Unable to log in", err);
      });
  };
```

The FetchError class uses the 'http-status-codes' node module to look up the textual description.

errors.ts:

```
import * as HttpStatus from 'http-status-codes';

export class BaseError extends Error {
  constructor(message) {
    super(message);
    this.message = message;
  }
}

export class FetchError extends BaseError {
  statusCode: number;
  statusText: string;
  description: string;

  constructor(message: string, err: any) {
    super(message);

    if (err instanceof Response) {
      var resp = <Response>err;
      this.statusCode = resp.status;

      if (resp.status == 12029)
        this.statusText = "A connection to server could not be established";
      else
        this.statusText = HttpStatus.getStatusText(resp.status);

      resp.json()
        .then(body => {
          this.description = body.Message;
          console.log(`Error: ${this.message}, Status: ${this.statusText}, Code: ${this.statusCode}, Description: ${this.description}`);
        })
    }
    else if (err instanceof Error) {
      var error = <Error>error;
      this.description = err.message;
      console.log(`Error: ${this.message}, Description: ${this.description}`);
    }
    else {
      this.description = "???";
      console.log(`Unknown error: ${this.message}`);
    }
  }
}
```

I'm sure there are better ways of doing this. I'm still getting my head around this.