# Aurelia auth - custom response message - console error

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, aurelia, aurelia-auth

Using [this](https://github.com/paulvanbladel/aurelia-auth) aurelia-auth plugin together with .NET Core webAPI, I wish to return a custom error when user tries to log in with incorrect username and/or password.

**WebAPI:**

```
public HttpResponseMessage Login()
{
    if (passwordValid)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(new LoginResponseViewModel { Token = token });
    }
    else
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Incorrect username or password!");
    }
}
```

**Script**

```
logIn(email, password) {
    return this.auth.login(email, password)
        .then(response => {
            console.log("success logged " + response);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log("login failure: " + err);
        });
}
```

1. How do I access my unauthorized response custom message "Incorrect username or password" in the login function catch error?
2. It seems like the aurelia-auth login function must receive a `httpStatusCode.Unauthorized` in order for it to understand that the password/username was incorrect, but that generates a `401 (Unauthorized)` console error. Can I suppress this console error or perhaps return a json result which aurelia-auth understands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 1. How to access custom unauthorized response message

**Server response:**

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "My message");
```

**Client:**

```
return this.auth.login(email, password)
    .then(response => {
        console.log("success logged " + response);
    })
    .catch(error => error.json().then(serverError =>
        console.log(serverError) //My message 
    ));
```

### 2. Suppress console error or return a json result which aurelia-auth understands

It is not possible in the current version of aurelia-auth to return a json result that aurelia-auth understand.

I decided to replace my current [aurelia-auth](https://github.com/paulvanbladel/aurelia-auth) package with [aurelia-authentication](https://github.com/SpoonX/aurelia-authentication).

[Aurelia-authentication](https://github.com/SpoonX/aurelia-authentication) is fork of [aurelia-auth](https://github.com/paulvanbladel/aurelia-auth) which itself is a port of the great [Satellizer library](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer/). With the new package I can now do much more, (refresh token, return custom messages from server etc)..